# How to update permission or add email in google form API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, google-forms-api

How to update permission or add email in google form API? 
Want to add email to be able to edit the form. 
I would like to know how to set up permissions for email access to google form?

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {JWT} = require('google-auth-library');

// Replace with your own values
const CLIENT_EMAIL = '';
const PRIVATE_KEY =  '';
const FORM_NAME = 'My Form';
const QUESTION_TITLE = 'What is your favorite color?';
const QUESTION_CHOICES = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'];

// Set up a JWT client using your credentials
const authClient = new JWT({
  email: CLIENT_EMAIL,
  key: PRIVATE_KEY,
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.body']
});

// Create a new form
async function createForm() {
  try {
    // Authenticate with the Google Forms API
    await authClient.authorize();

    // Create a new form object
    const form = {
        info: {
            title: FORM_NAME , documentTitle: QUESTION_TITLE
        },
    };

    // Call the Google Forms API to create the form
    const response = await google.forms({version: 'v1', auth: authClient}).forms.create({resource: form});
  console.log(`FORM_ID ${response.data.formId}`)
  const res = await google.forms({version: 'v1', auth: authClient}).forms.get({formId: response.data.formId});
  console.log(res.data);
    // Add a multiple choice question to the form
    const question = {
      title: QUESTION_TITLE,
      questionItem: {
        question: {
         required: true,
          choiceQuestion: {
            type:"RADIO",
            options: QUESTION_CHOICES.map((options) => ({ value: options }))
          }
        }
      }
    };

   //  Call the Google Forms API to add the question to the form
    const questionResponse = await google.forms({version: 'v1', auth: authClient}).forms.batchUpdate({
      formId: response.data.formId,
      resource: {
        requests: [{
          createItem: {
            item: question
            ,location: { index: 0 },
          } 
        }, 
    ], 
      }

    });

 
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

createForm();
```

I've tried accessing the google form link, but I'm not able to access it.

[image]

have tried forms.permissions.update but google form api doesn't have function to add permissions

```
const res = await google.forms({version: 'v1', auth: authClient}).forms.permissions.update({
  fileId: 'FORM_ID',
  permissionId: 'PERMISSION_ID',
  requestBody: {
    role: 'writer',
    type: 'user',
    emailAddress: 'user@example.com',
  },
});
```

Comment: I use Service Accounts it seems can't use another email to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `const res = await google.forms({version: 'v1', auth: authClient}).forms.permissions.update({,,,`, it seems that you try to use the method of Drive API using the client of Forms API. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. And, in this case, "Permissions: create" is required to be used instead of "Permissions: update". When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
console.log(`FORM_ID ${response.data.formId}`)
```

#### To:

```
console.log(`FORM_ID ${response.data.formId}`);
// I added the below script.
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth: authClient});
const res = await drive.permissions.create({
  fileId: response.data.formId,
  requestBody: {
    role: "writer",
    type: "user",
    emailAddress: "user@example.com", //  Please set your email address.
  },
});
console.log(res.data);
```

- When this modified script is run, the created Google Form is shared with `user@example.com`. If this email is a Google account, you can see the Google Form at "Shared with me".

#### Reference:

- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

Comment: Do you have some sample code to set read-only permissions to the form or access to form-only queries?

Comment: @Ratanon-63015144 About your new question of `Do you have some sample code to set read-only permissions to the form or access to form-only queries?`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. In this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. By this, it will help users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: My problem has been solved, thanks. I fixed it by getting the "responderUri" value.